# Modify other elements using class using css/less

Tags: css, less

So, trying to get some help om if/how this would be done.
I have a list of canvas elements on a page horizontally. I would like to have the behaviour that if I click on one of them, the OTHERS should get a width of 100px.
I'm in control of the click event on each canvas only, so I'm able to add a "selected" class on the canvas to be in focus. If no canvas have the selected class they should use their "default" value, but when selected is added, it does nothing to the canvas itself but finds all other canvases that doesn't have the selected class and change their width.

Comment: you can use the `:not` selector but that only works if at least one canvas has that class. I'm also not sure that this is really a CSS issue, sounds more like a JS issue to me and should be solved with JS.

Comment: I'm not saying it's an issue to solve it using JS, but I would prefer doing it, if possible, using CSS which looks lika a better option here instead of spreading JS-code around the place.

Comment: the thing is, you have a condition here: (one element has the class 'selected' === true/false). Conditions can be handled neither by CSS nor by LESS/SASS. At least the condition needs to be handled with JS.

Comment: Could you show us your HTML structure? For example, do the canvases have a common parent? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with putting code into your question.

Answer (score 0):

So my solution is to use the CSS pseudo-class `:focus`.
And to enable it to do so, you need to set `tabindex` for the canvas elements first.

Here my example:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.canvas-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.canvas-div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.canvas-div:focus {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="canvas-container">
      <canvas
        class="canvas-div"
        height="100"
        tabindex="0"
        style="background: pink;"
      >
      </canvas>
      <canvas
        class="canvas-div"
        height="100"
        tabindex="0"
        style="background: yellowgreen;"
      >
      </canvas>
      <canvas
        class="canvas-div"
        height="100"
        tabindex="0"
        style="background: orangered;"
      >
      </canvas>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the canvases have a common parent you can do this using the CSS :has (currently supported by major browsers except Firefox where the user has to set a flag to enable it) and CSS :not.

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container:has(>.selected) canvas:not(.selected) {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <canvas width="200" height="300"></canvas><canvas width="200" height="300" class="selected"></canvas><canvas width="200" height="300"></canvas><canvas width="200" height="300"></canvas>
</div>
```